# If $a$ and $b$ are co-primes, and $p$ is prime, factoring $a \cdot p + b$ will eventually always generate a new larger prime $q$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Let $a$ and $b$ be co-primes, $p$ prime, and $f_0 = p$.

Let $f_{(n+1)} = SPF(a \cdot f_n + b) \cdot f_n $, where $SPF(x)$ is the smallest prime factor of $x$.

Repeat until $SPF(a \cdot f_n + b) = a \cdot f_n + b $, then we have found the new prime $q = a \cdot \prod^n_{j=1} f_n + b$.

Example:
\begin{align*}
a &=6666 \\
b &=47 \\
f_0 &= 7 \\
6666 \cdot 7 + 47 &=13 \cdot 3593 \implies f_1 =7 \cdot 13 \\
6666 \cdot 7 \cdot 13+47 &=606653 \\
SPF(606653) &= 606653 
\end{align*}
So $q= 606653$ is the new prime!

I've tried this for a lot of different combinations, it always seems to work or leads to a number $f_n$ that I was not able to factor. 
It's kind of ironical that factoring will lead to a new prime. It's almost as if the composite number "knows" how to find a new prime. Why is this the case? And is it possible to proof that this algorithm will always produce a new prime?

Comment: Isn't $SMO(x)$ always 1?

Comment: @gowrath: I think he means to say smallest prime factor. I am not certain, though.

Comment: Thanks, I meant smallest prime factor. Edited accordingly.

Comment: Yes, this is Dirichlet's Theorem on prime numbers in disguise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be mistaken but I think you are leveraging Drichlet's Theorem in some form. The theorem, as stated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) is:

> For any two coprime integers $a$ and $b$, there are infinitely many primes of the form $a + nb$ for a non-negative integer $n$. Stated otherwise, there are infinitely many primes in the arithmetic progression $a + nb$.

You pick two coprime integers $a$ and $b$ and the thing you are doing by multiplying $a$ by some primes is essentially just marching through the arithmetic progression of $b + na$ (albeit rather haphazardly). That condition that $SPF(a\cdot f_n + b) = a\cdot f_n + b$ is just a primality test in disguise.

So in essence, a better version of your algorithm would be:

Pick two coprime integers $a$ and $b$ and let $f_0 = 0$. Let $f_{n+1} = f_n + 1$ and repeat until $SPF(a\cdot f_n + b) = a\cdot f_n + b$ or, in other words, until $a\cdot f_n + b$ is prime. Such a number must exist by Drichlet's theorem since there are infinitely many primes in the arithmetic progression $b + na$. Thus we have found a bigger prime.

Because you jump around the arithmetic progression in larger leaps than a linear march, there is a chance that you may "miss" the primes in the sequence. However proving/disproving your way will always find a prime is definitely nontrivial.

Comment: The algorithm leaves out many members of the arithmetic progression $an + b$. We don't have $f_{n+1} = f_n + 1$, but $f_{n+1} = q\cdot f_n$, where $q$ is the smallest prime dividing $af_n + b$. It is at least thinkable that it happens to step over all primes in that progression.

Comment: @DanielFischer you're absolutely right. I had the same reservations but i feel proving it one way or the other is non trivial.

Comment: @gowrath. Thank for your answer. Drichlet's Theorem explains why it has a chance of working but that does not explain the most essential part: is it better to multiply by the smallest prime factor because it helps to find the prime faster. For example if the first result is an even number the smallest factor would be 2 ensuring the next result is always odd. If there is no value in the factoring then using a random prime would have to work just as good which is clearly not the case.

Comment: @pietfermat My first inclination would be to say that the fastest way of finding a prime would be to linearly search through the arithmetic progression as described in my answer. Your method of multiplying grows the numbers too quickly and primes get less dense as numbers get larger.

Comment: I know it's not the most efficient way to find a larger prime. Factoring large numbers is even harder than determining primality. I am looking for the mechanism behind this part of the algorithm. Factoring seems to efficiently lead to a much larger prime. The algorithm found 606653 in two passes as linear searching would take 91 tries before reaching the same prime.

Comment: @pietfermat You are thinking about this the wrong way. Factoring isn't efficiently leading to a much larger prime, it's efficiently leading to a large number which then happens to be prime. It would only take 91 steps to reach a prime linearly if you started at 1. If you wanted a large prime, you'd start searching linearly at a larger initial value for the coefficient of $a$. You also literally have only one example showing your method's "efficient" way of finding a large prime. As you mentioned, in other cases it probably got too large to even compute.

Comment: Thanks again. I could add many other examples but I think I have answered my own question with the comment on the even  numbers. I also noticed "patterns" in the sequential solutions:
5, 7, 13, 17, 21, 25, 45, 51, 63, 75, 77, 81 ,93, 103 are the first 14 solutions to my example, many are prime or semi-prime increasing the chances of a prime by using a factor.